# Connecting Java standalone server to Nest cloud via Firebase-Api

Tags: java, firebase, nest-api

I would like to connect a Java application to the Nest-Cloud via the Firebase-Api. The application is as simple as reading the setpoint of a nest thermostat.

I spent a lot of time on developer.nest.com and firebase.com to find the required information, but failed.

1. What is actually the base url, where the firebase is located? seems not to be home.nest.com
2. How can I authenticate without user interaction? I tried FirebaseSimpleLogin, but the implementation depens on Android, which is not my platform.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

For 1) I don't know for sure, but have you tried `https://api.home.nest.com` and `https://developer-api.nest.com`?

2) The user has to authenticate and allow the client you're developing at least once. You'll need to get an authorization code, which you get from the client page on the Nest developer site. The code is six characters I think, and you'll have to include that in your code or assign to a variable and call it.

Take a look at [another entry I made](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24601798/acquiring-and-changing-basic-data-on-the-nest-thermostat). If nothing else, it might help you get a little farther down your rabbit trail.

Comment: the base url for the firebase protocol will be https://developer-api.nest.com. However you'll use https://api.home.nest.com URLs for getting an access token, which you'll need to access data at developer-api.nest.com

Comment: @mccv so how about setting values to the thermo stat? do we have to use the base url or the https://api.home.nest.com url?

Comment: @Mr.Noob api.home.nest.com is for authorization and token exchange. The rest goes through developer-api.nest.com