# Android Http put in REST similar to curl -d

Tags: java, android, curl, nest-api

How do you translate curl -d "65" to a java httpput entry?  I need to do the curl commands here in this link to java using java apache http library.

[Acquiring and changing basic data on the Nest thermostat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24601798/acquiring-and-changing-basic-data-on-the-nest-thermostat/24616406#24616406)

Here is the curl command:

curl -v -L -X PUT "https://developer-api.nest.com/devices/thermostats/THERMOSTAT_ID/target_temperature_f?auth=AUTH_CODE" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "65"

here is my java code :

```
httpPut.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");     
HttpEntity put_entity =  new StringEntity("65"); // Problem is here, I think!
httpPut.setEntity(put_entity);           // or here!
HttpResponse put_response = httpclient.execute(httpPut);
```

Comment: What error are you getting? It might be that you're not allowing redirects?

Comment: If you're building on Android, you may want to side-step this issue and try out the Firebase Android client. It has a learning curve (like any client libs) but the performance is much better than rest + httpPut.  https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/quickstart.html

Comment: There is also some Android sample code using the firebase APIs in the following github link https://github.com/nestlabs/android-NestDK. The firebase logic is separated into a separate library and should be useful for setting/reading the various fields exposed via the Nest API.